# Spring boot applicaiton unable to find SQLite jdbc driver class

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, hibernate

In my Spring boot application I have the dependency for sqlite jdbc driver specified:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.34.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and in pom.xml properties

```
<hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
```

and have the below in my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.springboot.sqlite.SQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:cryptobot.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.sqlite.JDBC
```

The SQLDialect class I have provided is copied from [this article](https://fullstackdeveloper.guru/2020/05/01/how-to-integrate-sqlite-database-with-spring-boot/).
But running the application fails with

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
> at com.binance.bot.BinancebotApplication.main(BinancebotApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to run it without providing any properties but  spring.datasource.url ? Of course, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa should be in dependencies too.

Comment: Without any properties how would I specify the JDBC driver name? I do have JPA in my dependencies <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: @HughDarling Did you configured **SQLDialect** by extending `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect`.

Comment: what version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: Yes, com.springboot.sqlite.SQLDialect is my own, that I infact copied from the article you mentioned.

Comment: I retried now after several days and somehow it is showing a different error now: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider

Comment: than please update your question which includes the latest exception . And most importantly , what spring-boot version are you using ? I may have idea if you tell me this information.

Comment: Version is 2.6.1. updated new stacktrace in question.

Comment: @HughDarling. Just update my answer . It should solve your problem. Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This main problem is that you are explicitly configure to use Hibernate 5.1.0 by the following configuration in `pom.xml`

```
<hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
```

which is too old (released 6 years ago) and spring-boot 2.6.1 is no longer support it for a long time.

Technically, spring-boot 2.6 is based on spring 5.3 and spring 5.3 is developed and test against Hibernate 5.3+ , and try to be backwards-compatible with Hibernate 5.2 at runtime on a best-effort basis. You can find such info at the javadoc of [`HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.html) and this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25533) .

It tries to load the `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` at some point but this class only exist since Hibernate 5.2. As you are using Hibernate 5.1 now and hence it complains it cannot load it with the following error:

> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method
> 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider

So simply remove the above `<hibernate.version>` in `pom.xml` such that it will use the hibernate 5.6.1 defined by spring-boot 2.6.1 and your problem should then be solved. It does not make sense to use a very old Hibernate version for a new project.

Comment: I printed the classpath and I do find sqlite-jdbc and a few other jdbcs, in this order: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.6.1/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.6.1.jar;org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.13/spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar;org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.34.0/sqlite-jdbc-3.34.0.jar

Comment: i know as you mention you somehow solve this problem which now make my answer not matched with your question now. i will look at your updated question later and update my answer after that. thanks

Comment: I removed hibernate.version in my pom.xml but still it is downloading and setting in classpath the hibernate 5.1.0 jars and fails with the same NoClassDefFound error for HibernatePersistenceProvider. I don't know where from the 5.1.0 final version is getting specified. I have done a mvn clean install but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @HughDarling execute `mvn dependency:tree` , it will show you which dependencies defined in the `pom.xml` will include hibernate 5.1.0.  Show me such result or the whole `pom.xml`

Comment: I have put pom.xml, the /tmp/jvm.out showing the running application classpath and the mvn dependency:tree output here: shorturl.at/tINY7.

Comment: Your `pom.xml` should be correct. So seem like it is your IDE configuration problem that cause it still includes hibernate 5.1.0 in the class-path . Can you try to refresh the project ? Or just create a new project to try again ?

Comment: yes, it works now, confirmed to be an IDE issue.

Comment: glad to hear. I will be appreciated if you could also consider to mark my answer to be the accepted answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this in my local machine and here the solution.

**You have to create your own dilect by extending org.hibernate.dialect**

```
package com.mehul.SQLiteDemo.dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;

public class SQLDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

        registerFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StringType.INSTANCE, "", "||", ""));
        registerFunction("mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "?1 % ?2"));
        registerFunction("substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE));
        registerFunction("substring", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE));
    }

    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        return "integer";
    }

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length() + 20).append(query).append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?")
                .toString();
    }

    public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
    }

    public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName, String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable,
            String[] primaryKey, boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also update `spring.jpa.database-platform=com.mehul.SQLiteDemo.dialect.SQLDialect` with your package and classname.

**Note** : I used `<hibernate.version>5.6.3.Final</hibernate.version>`

Answer (score 0):

Since, Hibernate doesn't ship with a Dialect for SQLite, you can follow the paths below:

### 1. Create your own dialect class by extending [Dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html).

```java
import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
 public SQLiteDialect() {
  super();
  registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
  registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
  registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
  registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
  registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
  registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
  registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
  registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
  registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
  registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
  registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
  registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
  .
  .
  .
 }
}
```

[Click](https://www.programmerall.com/article/6963531561/) for the complete example.

### 2. You can use 3rd party dialects.

For **Hibernate 5** add the [dependency](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/):

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the configuration:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```